# Input format of generalized dissimilarity model (gdm)

Tags: r, environment-variables, distance, similarity, mixed-models

I am using the **gdm** package and I tried it for bioData using both format 1 and 4 in the formatsitepair command. But the results are different shown as below:

*format 1*: site-by-species matrix

[site-by-species matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YM1xv.png)

```
gdm_input1 <- formatsitepair(bioData = bio1, bioFormat = 1, dist = "jaccard", abundance = FALSE, siteColumn = "site", XColumn = "longitude", YColumn = "latitude", predData = env)
```

*result 1* formatsitepair:

[result format 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQeuF.png)

*format 4*: site-distance table

[site-distance table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJ5Qb.png)

```
gdm_input4 <- formatsitepair(bioData = bio4, bioFormat = 4, dist = "jaccard", abundance = FALSE, siteColumn = "site", XColumn = "longitude", YColumn = "latitude", predData = env)
```

*result 2* formatsitepair:

It shows the same dataframe as my input dataframe - [site-distance table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJ5Qb.png)

I don't understand why this didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is because format 4 requires not just one value for a site but all the possible site-pair combinations of each site with every other site!!